# Runtime error 13 :Type mismatch

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am trying to execute a simple code to create a Pivot Table using my data.

```
Sub PTable()
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
rng.Select

Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rng)
Sheets("New").Activate
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PTCache, Range("A1"), "My_PT")
End Sub
```

Runtime error 13, Type Mismatch is thrown while setting PTCache. This has been happening very frequently whenever I am working with Pivot Tables on my excel using VBA.

Comment: which line do you get the error?

Comment: While setting Pivot Cache, although my rng object selects the desired range.

Comment: Try to set on this line breakpoint and look all variables (`xlDatabase`, `rng`) in watch.

Comment: xlDatabase is 1... nothing else through breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

This string `Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))` is setting very huge range `"$1:$1048576"`. 
You can watch it in debugger:

```
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Address
=> "$1:$1048576"
```

Maybe something wrong with the range, that you want to use in `ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create`?

Try also use this [Microsoft's advice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839430.aspx) about second argument `PivotCache.Create`:

> When passing as a range, it is recommended to either use a string to
>   specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named
>   range and pass the name as a string. Passing a **Range** object may
>   cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly.

Comment: Yes, the range I am working on is huge (rows of the order 100000). My code works fine for smaller ranges but, what's pulling the trigger for a gigantic range.

Comment: I think use PivotCache.Create on such a huge range may use too much memory.

Comment: By the way, 100000 rows is less than the whole table, as you wrote. Why do you need it all?

Comment: Tested for a data set of A1:AD50000, works fine. For my original Data Set A1:AD172000, it is throwing Type Mismatch error. I can probably be a limitation of PivotCache.Create, is there any way one can sort it out.

Comment: Try to use Microsoft's advice (I added citation in Answer)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might try

```
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

which is like Ctrl+Shift+* instead of

```
Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
```

Performing a single method (i.e., `.CurrentRegion`) instead of two methods (i.e., `xlToRight` followed by `xlDown`) is likely to be less memory intensive and resolve the Type Mismatch glitch.

Comment: Thanks for a more efficient way of replicating Ctrl+Shift+*. But, I am still getting the 'Mismatch' error for rows>60000

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. I had a code working perfectly until the number of rows was over 60.000 lines, then error 13 :Type mismatch appeared when creating the PivotCache...

Solution: Instead of using a Range variable to store the range do it in a string variable. That way (I don't know why) you can avoid having that error. This code should work:

```
Sub PTable()
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
'Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim RangeString As String
Dim SheetName As String

'Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
'rng.Select

LastRow = UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastColumn = UsedRange.Columns.Count
SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
RangeString = SheetName & "!R1C1:R" & LastRow & "C" & LastColumn

Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, RangeString)
Sheets("New").Activate
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PTCache, Range("A1"), "My_PT")
End Sub
```